# android Kotlin coroutine execution order

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I'm having trouble with how the coroutine executes the code.
I have 2 functions below:

```
 private fun test1() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            Log.d("Test", "1")

            delay(1000)

            launch {
                Log.d("Test", "2")
            }
            Log.d("Test", "3")
        }// print 1, 2, 3
    }

private fun test2() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        Log.d("Test", "1")

        launch {
            Log.d("Test", "2")
        }
        Log.d("Test", "3")
    }// print 1, 3, 2
}
```

In my understanding, the lifecycleScope uses Dispatcher.Main.immediate. So test1 is reasonable. But why does the test2 function print 1,3,2. I just remote delay the function.
I have run many times and it prints the same output

Comment: I guess if you run `test1()` a couple of times you will also see `1, 3, 2`. Because it is not guarantee that the coroutine, launched within another coroutine, will start execution immediately.

Comment: I have run it many times and it prints the same output. I think test1() is reasonable because the lifecycleScope uses Dispatcher.Main.immediate so it execute immediately

Comment: The `lifecycleScope` in `test2()` also uses the `Dispatcher.Main.immediate,` but the output is different. I would't rely on the order in that cases.